# Vue.js: Allow a checkbox in a td to be clickable anywhere in the td

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My problem is a pretty simple one, there must be a simple solution.
I have a table, and a checkbox on each row.

```
<tr v-repeat="claim: claims">
    <td  v-on="click: claim.selected = !claim.selected">
        <input  v-model="claim.selected" type="checkbox">
    </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is, it works when clicking around the input, within the td, but when I click on the input directly, it automatically gets unselected because of the on click of the surrounding td. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your code into a method and call `.stopPropagation()` on the event. Something like this:

```
<tr v-repeat="claim: claims">
    <td  v-on="click: clicked">
        <input  v-model="claim.selected" type="checkbox">
    </td>
</tr>
```

with code:

```
[...]
methods: {
    clicked: function (event) {
        this.claim.selected = !this.claim.selected;
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing something like this.